# Django 1.5 error when sending attachments 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to send an attachment via email, a pdf but I get the following error `'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Here's my code.

```
created_pdf = open(filename)

from_email = settings.DEFAULT_EMAIL
email = EmailMessage('KenyaBuzz Tickets for %s'%seat1.movie, "There's a pdf attached with the tickets, please print it and provide it at...", from_email,
        [seat1.user.email],
        )
email.attach(filename, created_pdf, 'application/pdf')
email.send()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter to `attach` should be the data, not the file object.

```
email.attach(filename, created_pdf.read(), 'application/pdf')
```

But it's better to use `attach_file`, which takes a filename directly:

```
email.attach_file(filename)
```